# Google+ snippet description and title of page not showing

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

This is my code which i have added inside head of my website [eravikant.com](http://www.eravikant.com)

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="MySMSBuddy">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Description of my webpage">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://eravikant.com/images/image.png">

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

and code which which will show google+ icon for +1 is

```
<div align="right"><g:plusone size="medium" callback="MySMSBuddy" href="http://eravikant.com/images/image.png"></g:plusone></div>
```

But, when i click on +1. then only image of my website has share not description and title..

Need help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need **itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"** in your HTML tag:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
```

Comment: I tried that and now it gets the custom title, but the description is still blank on google plus. I've set meta description, og:description, and itemprop description.